# Javascript - Best Practices Using Multiple try/catch within Asynchronous Functions

Tags: javascript, exception

I've got two files containing asynchronous calls, wrapped in try/catches:

index.js

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        const data = await Service.getData()
    } catch (e) {
        // do some error handling
    }
}
```

Service.js

```
const Service = {
    getData: async () => {
        try {
            const data = await callApi()
        } catch (e) {
            // do some more error handling
        }
     }
 }
```

Is the try/catch necessary within `fetchData()`, since there's already a try/catch in `getData()`? i.e., is it enough to refactor like so...

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await Service.getData()
}
```

...while letting the service method do all the error handling?

I know this may be a simple question of how to scaffold error handling and personal preference, but I'm mostly looking for what others would implement to reduce boilerplate code

Comment: Its enough to have 1 try catch block per function. If you want to return different messages you can throw .

Answer (score 3):

try cache block is only required in the `Service` as it is calling API which may return the error sometimes.